# Is there a general way to communicate the idea of a non-A where A is any noun?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese, negation, nouns, prefixes

I’m trying to say “Survivorship bias is a logical fallacy that leads to the consideration of survivors as opposed to **non-survivors**.” Is there a way to say non-survivors, or more so non-anything? For example, non-frog, non-blanket… Is there a general way to make a noun a non-noun? I can’t seem to find a way to do this anywhere.

Comment: "Non-survivors" is 非生存者, but outside academic contexts, you should say 蛙ではない生き物, 毛布以外の物 and so on.

Comment: @naruto Thank you! How would you pronounce 非生存者?

Comment: It's pronounced ひせいぞんしゃ.